# Converting LatLng

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple weather app. At the beginning, the coordinates were specified in the code, but i added a ***Place Picker API*** to simply choose a place where i want to know weather. Place Picker returns coordinates like

***"lat/lng: (53.5722088,-1.189055)"*** 
  by  ***place.getLatLng();***.

But i need to put it in ***asyncTask.execute("Latitude", "Longitude")***.

is there any way to transform it like this?

Comment: You can just sen `latlng` instead of sending them seprately. or if you want to send it seprately only, then you can get them from the `latlng.getLatitude`

Comment: You can split that latlong with ",".

Answer (score 1):

Try as below

```
place.getLatLng().latitude; //For Latitude
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch value of latitude and longitude in a separate variable like this :

```
LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
String latitude = String.valueOf(latLng.latitude);
String longitude = String.valueOf(latLng.longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get LatLang through this..

```
 String latitute = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().getLatitude());
 String longitute = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().getLongitude());
```

and you just pass your `latitute` and `longitute` in your `asyncTask.execute()` method like this..

```
asyncTask.execute(latitute, longitute)
```